# Salesforce OAuth callback URL for Mobile SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, oauth, salesforce

I know, when using OAuth you can catch the callback URL by having custom schema in ios.

Using the Salesforce template I can not find the custom schema - How du Salesforce know 
when using Salesforce Mobile SDK on iOS for bouth Native Apps and Hybrid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a [custom URL for your app](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/), you can specify an URL as `oauth_callback` in the request token step of the OAuth flow. That way Salesforce will know where to redirect to on the device. Say for example `myappname://salesforce-callback` which will intercept the `oauth_verifier` after the user has verified your request token.

To further clarify: once the user has authorized your request token by entering Salesforce username and password, a HTTP redirect response is formulated by them to the specified callback. If the callback redirect leads to a URL that maps to an app on the user's device; iOS intercepts it and passes it to the app.

Comment: Hmm, that depends on which version of OAuth you are trying to use to access them. OAuth1.0a or OAuth 2. The answer I gave should be possible with OAuth1.0a.